# Oracle query to list all occurrences of a string and its subsequent values from CLOB field

Tags: regex, oracle, loops, clob

I have a CLOB field in my Oracle table and would like to extract all occurrences of the string that matches the pattern 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint' and its subsequent values (which are separated by '|' ).

**Sample Data-**

```
|-1080|0833|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint010|F28028079|0820|3.3 02/17/14080|080|080|031|00879|[0-0]?[3.3 02/17/14-3.3 02/17/14]?[0833]|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011|F28028081|080|080|080|080|032|-1080|032|-1032|-1080|032|-1080|032|-1080|0833|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint013|F28028007|0820|
```

For the above-provided example, I used the below query to get all occurrences of the string 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint' and its subsequent values (separated by | ) from the CLOB data.

The query is able to get all the occurrences of '**RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint**', but returns only the first subsequent value in all the rows.

**Query - **

```
select objectid, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint[^\|]+', 1,column_value) column1, 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(DATA, '([^\|]+)', 1, 3) AS column2
from test_table cross join table(cast(multiset(select level 
from dual connect by level <= regexp_count(DATA, 'RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint') ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
```

**Actual Result -**

| objectid | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint010 | F28028079 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 | F28028079 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint013 | F28028079 |

**Expected Result -**

| objectid | column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint010 | F28028079 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 | F28028081 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint013 | F28028007 |

I'm new to writing queries and any suggestion would be helpful.

Thank you !!

Comment: Well, your second regexp has a hard-coded `3` - should that just be `3 * column_value`? Or are there lines in your CLOB that don't match your RES pattern? (Which can be handled by counting lines, then filtering for that pattern instead, if necessary?)

Comment: @AlexPoole - The CLOB has other lines that don't match the RES pattern. I need to get all the RES occurrences and their subsequent value. Please find example in the below comment.

Comment: 4 mg, oral, 1 tablet three times a day032|-1080|0833|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint086|F62801080|0820|3.3         02/17/14080|080|080|031|00879|[0-0]?[3.3         02/17/14-3.3         02/17/14]?[0-0]?[0-0]?[0-0]?[0-0]?[0-0]032|-1032|-1080|032|-1080|080|080|080|0821|2/17/2014 12:00:00 AM080|0811|DataType_10032|-1080|032|-1080|0833|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint086|F62802080|080|080|080|080|032|-1080|032|-1032|-1080|032|-1080|080|080|080|080|080|080|032|-1080|032|-1080|0833|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint086|F62803080|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need regular expression for this; although it is more to type you will probably find that simple string functions are faster than regular expressions:

```sql
WITH line_bounds (objectid, data, spos, epos) AS (
  SELECT objectid,
         data,
         1,
         INSTR(data, CHR(10), 1)
  FROM   test_table
UNION ALL
  SELECT objectid,
         data,
         epos + 1,
         INSTR(data, CHR(10), epos + 1)
  FROM   line_bounds
  WHERE  epos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY objectid SET orderid,
lines (objectid, line) AS (
  SELECT objectid,
         CASE epos
         WHEN 0
         THEN SUBSTR(data, spos)
         ELSE SUBSTR(data, spos, epos -spos)
         END
  FROM   line_bounds
),
match_bounds (objectid, line, res_spos, res_epos, next_epos) AS (
  SELECT objectid,
         line,
         INSTR(line, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint'),
         INSTR(line, '|', INSTR(line, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint') + 1, 1),
         INSTR(line, '|', INSTR(line, '|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint') + 1, 2)
  FROM   lines
)
SELECT objectid,
       SUBSTR(line, res_spos + 1, res_epos - res_spos - 1) AS column1,
       SUBSTR(line, res_epos + 1, next_epos - res_epos - 1) AS column2
FROM   match_bounds
WHERE  res_spos > 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table (objectid, data) AS
SELECT 12345,
       EMPTY_CLOB() || '|-1080|0833|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint010|F28028079|0820|3.3 02/17/14080|080|080|031|
|00879|[0-0]?[3.3 02/17/14-3.3 02/17/14]?[0833]|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011|F28028081|080|080|080|080|032|-1080|032|-1032|-1080|032|-1080|032|
|-1080|0833|RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint013|F28028007|0820|'
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| OBJECTID | COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint010 | F28028079 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint011 | F28028081 |
| 12345 | RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint013 | F28028007 |

---

If you did want to use regular expressions (please compare the two solutions performance on your data) then you can match the entire pattern and extract the value of the capturing groups:

```sql
select objectid, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         DATA,
         '\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|',
         1,
         column_value,
         NULL,
         1
       ) AS column1, 
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(
         DATA,
         '\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|',
         1,
         column_value,
         NULL,
         2
       ) AS column2
from   test_table
       cross join table(
         cast(
           multiset(
             select level 
             from   dual
             connect by level <= regexp_count(DATA, '\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|')
           ) as sys.odcinumberlist
         )
       )
```

Which has the same output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wlyc4OBC)

Comment: @AR91 No, you need a regular expression that has 3 capturing groups to be able to extract the value form the third capturing group. `'\|(RES_GetResData_Public_ScreenPrint.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|'` See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/99tTXNdD) for an example for both solutions.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It works like a charm !!

Comment: Hi there !! I wanted to check with you regarding the performance optimization of the query. Since CLOB does not support parallel processing, the time taken to process huge volumes of data (millions) is high. Kindly let me know if there are any other alternatives to SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY / CONNECT BY that would improve the performance. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks in advance.